# How to grep for all strings alphanumeric of a certain length in every file in a directory?

Tags: regex, string, grep, full-text-search

I have a bunch of files of random characters in several sub directories and am trying to grab every string of 8 consecutive alphanumeric characters from all the files. Preferable each on a separate line in a txt file.

I've tried a bunch of grepping with a poor attempt at regex. Here's what I have so far and it doesn't work at all.

`grep -r '^[a-z0-9]{8}$' > file.txt`

Absolutely no output in the console or file.txt.
I'd like a file that looks like:
`3hf7fj58`

`3jf85he7`

`3hd75jfu`

...etc

Answer (score 2):

The regular expression you are using is considered to be an Extended Regexp. For `grep` to treat the expression as extended you need a -E flag.

```
grep -r -E '^[a-z0-9]{8}$' >output.txt
```

Also you expressed in your example output that you would like the matches to be space delimited, not newline delimited.  You can achieve that by piping through `tr`

```
grep -r -E '^[a-z0-9]{8}$' |tr "\n" " " >output.txt
```

`tr` means transliteration, which means to translate one character to another. Here we're converting newlines in the output of `grep` into spaces.

**Update**: As has been pointed out in a comment, `xargs` also takes a newline delimited stream and converts it to space delimited (by default), so the above could be written like this:

```
grep -r -E '^[a-z0-9]{8}$' |xargs >output.txt
```

Comment: OP example and yours lack input file.   Also, `| xargs` is equivalent to your `| tr ...`.  And I'm lazy, so that's what I type.

Comment: An input file isn't needed. `grep -r` will act recursively on the current working directory. `xargs` saves a few keystrokes and may be more familiar to someone who hasn't used `tr` much, so that's a valid point.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short `gnu awk` if you can use it instead of `grep`

Example file

```
3hf7fj58 3jf85he7 3hd75jfu
hello this1234 notthis hereisanoter
```

```
awk -v RS="[ \t\n]+" 'length($1)==8' file
3hf7fj58
3jf85he7
3hd75jfu
this1234
```

- Set the record separator to any number of space and newline `[ \t\n]+`
- Test if first field is 8 character long `length($1)==8`
- Since there are no action, do the default action, print the line

If you like to test the characters, ex do not print words with capital letter:

```
awk -v RS="[ \t\n]+" 'length($1)==8 && /^[a-z0-9]+$/' file
```

Only print words with `[a-z0-9]`

PS if you do not have tabs, you can remove `\t`